# Is WPS supported by OpenLayers 5?

Tags: openlayers, wps

As far as I can see the up to date version of OpenLayers is 5.2. I am trying to connect my OpenLayers to my WPS but I have no luck doing so. All the info I can get says that there was WPS support in version 2 but "now" (old sources) in version 3 it wasn't implemented. I can't find any sources on how this is in the current version...

All I tried did not succeed so I got the feeling that trying to connect to my WPS like I would do in version 2 won't work at all. Before I continue to try to connect OpenLayers and my WPS I would like to have this question clarified.

So code like this won't work or I am using it wrong?

```
// Create a WPSClient instance for use with the local GeoServer
this.wpsClient = new OpenLayers.WPSClient({
    servers: {
        local: '/geoserver/wps'
    }
});
```

Comment: nobody has some answers for me?

Comment: Quiet a few OGC service features were lost in OpenLayers > 2, so it's quite probable that your research is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The client itself like in the version 2 does not exist in Openlayers > 2. One has to build the XML file inside the Javascript and then post it to the WPS server.

Comment: did anything emerge on this topic in the last 2 years?